# Java rodando 2 programas em paralelo

Tags: java, paralelismo, inicialização

Estou usando o intellj e acabei de começar um curso gratuito.
Eu me desafiei a fazer um código em que você poe uma data e o programa diz o dia da semana, mas ao tentar rodar o código abre-se uma pequena janela escrito

```
 'DiaDaSemana' is not allowed to run in parallel. Would you like to stop the running one?
```

PS: DiaDaSemana é o nome do programa. A janela tem 2 botões (Stop and Rerun) e (Cancel), não importando o que eu ponha sempre acontece a mesma coisa. Me permite escrever no terminal(Run) e não roda mais nada, e o código não para de rodar sem nada acontecendo, aqui está o código:
PS: não ocorre nenhum erro.

```
public class DiaDaSemana {
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        int semana = 3;

        int dia = 22;               //ENTRE COM
        int mes = 7;                //OS SEUS
        boolean anoBicesto = false; //DADOS

        if (mes > 1) {

            if (anoBicesto == false) {    //Sem Ano Bicesto
                semana += 31 + 28;
            } else {                      // Com Ano Bicesto
                semana += 31 + 29;
            }
            mes -= 2;

            while (mes > 0) {       //Enquanto mes for maior q zero
                if (mes % 2 == 1) {      //Março == impar == 31
                    semana += 31;
                }
                if (mes % 2 == 0) {      //Abril == par == 30
                    semana += 30;
                }
            }
        }
        while (semana > 7) {     //tirando as semanas extras
            semana -= 7;
        }

        switch (semana) {        //Resultado!
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Domingo-Feriado");
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Segunda-Feira");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Terça-Feira");
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Quarta-Feira");
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Quinta-Feira");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Sexta-feira");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Sabado-Feriado");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("ERRO...ERRO...ERRO");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara o problema ta no seu código, o while da linha 22 ta em loop infinito o valor de "mes" nunca é alterado portanto não vai sair desse laço nunca

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro não está no código. É alguma coisa do IntelliJ. Aparentemente há um programa já em execução (talvez uma versão antiga que tivesse entrado em loop infinito) e você está tentando rodá-lo de novo enquanto a execução anterior está lá ainda rodando indefinidamente.

O que você tem que fazer é abortar a execução anterior.

O seu código também não é lá dos melhores e tem muita coisa nele que poderia ser melhorada. Mas isso daí já seria assunto para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Oque deveria fazer para abortar a execução anterior? Em minha defesa eu comecei a aprender java ha 3 dias na internet, e este é apenas o protótipo

Comment: @Nioty Você pode tentar localizá-lo no gerenciador de tarefas do windows e matar o processo.